# Mount new USB Drives automatically

Tags: usb, mount

is it possible that new USB drives mount automatically

at this time I have to mount all my pen drives with gnome disk utily,

So is there a script or service that recognize all new pen drives and mountes automatically?

Answer (score 0):

On [#1094669](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1094669) and [#1262270](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1262270), it seems that this is marked as `Won't fix`.
You can install `usbmount` for now. I tested it for a while on a VM. Seems to work fine.